# How to speed up put_item() operations in Python Boto?

Tags: python, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I am trying to speed up the transfer of records contained within a JSON file stored in an AWS S3 bucket to a AWS DynamoDB table. The records in the JSON file are stored as a list of dictionaries of the form `[{'id':'123', 'name':'abc'}, {'id':'456','name':'def'}, ...]` To perform the record transfer, I am using `table.batch_writer()` in Boto3. This code is contained within an AWS Lambda script, such that when the S3 bucket is populated with a new JSON object, the record transfer begins. I am finding that even with the maximum timeout set for AWS Lambda (15 minutes), the put_item() operations are not completing for all records, which are on average around 40K. The put_item() operations seem incredibly slow, which makes me think this is not the optimal way of transferring records from S3 to DynamoDB.

Is there a faster way of transferring JSON records from an S3 bucket to a DynamoDB table?

```py
import json
import boto3

s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb',region_name='us-east-2')

def lambda_handler(event, context, verbose=True):
    bucket = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
    json_filename = event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key']
    json_object = s3_client.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=json_filename)
    json_file = json_object['Body'].read()
    data_dict = json.loads(json_file)
    table = dynamodb.Table('the_dynamodb_table_name')
    with table.batch_writer() as batch:
        for rec in data_dict:
            batch.put_item(Item=rec)
```

Comment: How have you measured that `put_item` operation is a problem? If you have set low memory for your Lambda then CPU might be an issue (parsing and serializing JSON-s might not be so fast).
Also you could try creating multiple boto sessions and running multiple batch_writers in parallel.

Comment: How many is "all records"?

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest exploring the `batch_put_item()` method, which can write up to 16mb of data per batch

https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html#DynamoDB.Client.batch_write_item

Comment: Is not using `batch_put_item` the same as using `batch_writer()`? Source: https://www.pydoc.io/pypi/boto3-1.4.5/autoapi/dynamodb/table/index.html#dynamodb.table.TableResource.batch_writer